# Node.js Express route not working. 404 not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have axios post going to /users/add and I keep getting a 404 error.  Can anyone please give me some insight as to what I am doing wrong please.

**Server.js**

```
app.use("/users", require("./routes/users"));
```

makes it so that all users routes use the users controller

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const DATABASE = process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost/MongoSetup";

mongoose.connect(DATABASE, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
mongoose.connection.once("open", () =>
  console.log(`--> SERVER.JS: Connected to ${DATABASE}`)
);
mongoose.connection.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log(`Mongoose connection err:\n${err}`);
});

app.use("/exercises", require("./routes/exercises"));
app.use("/users", require("./routes/users"));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`--> SERVER.JS: Server Running: http://localhost:3000/`);
});
```

**routes/users.js**

```
router.route("/add").post((req, res)
```

should set up a route for users/add

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
let User = require("../models/user.model");

router.route("/").get((req, res) => {
    User.find()
        .then(users => res.json(users))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});

router.route("/add").post((req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;

    const newUser = new User({username});

    newUser.save()
        .then(() => res.json("User Added!"))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

**create-user.component.js**

```
axios.post("/users/add", user)
```

Should send the new user to /users/add

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class CreateUser extends Component {
  state = {
    username: "",
  };

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const user = {
        username: this.state.username
    }

    console.log(user);
    axios.post("/users/add", user)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data));

    this.setState({
        username: ""
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Create New User</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>Username: </label>
                <input 
                    required
                    name="username"
                    className="form-control"
                    value={this.state.username}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create User" className="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does /users/ work for you?

Comment: No it should render the users.. I even added a test user and nothing gets returned when I hit /users

Comment: does it return 404 as well?

Comment: No network tab says it has a status code of 304

Comment: Try to first fix that route to make sure that everything works. Try to return some simple text instead of user in /users/. Make sure that there are no other errors in the node console.

Comment: @DmytroHuz Yea its not responding either. It wont display anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create express router instance only once and use it across all your routers (`users` and `exercises`).

**create a file for route factory**

```js
const usersRoutes = require('../usersRoutes');
const exercisesRoutes = require('../exercisesRoutes');
const routerWapper = (router) => {
    usersRoutes(router)
    exercisesRoutes(router)

    return router
};
module.exports = routerWapper;
```

**app.js**

```js
...
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = app.router();
...
app.use('/', () => routerWapper(router));
...
```

**user route**

```js
const userRoutes = (router) => {
    router.get("/users").get((req, res) => {
        User.find()
            .then(users => res.json(users))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
    });

    router.get("/users/add").post((req, res) => {
        const username = req.body.username;

        const newUser = new User({username});

        newUser.save()
            .then(() => res.json("User Added!"))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
    });
};
```

**exercise route**

```js
const exercisesRoutes = (router) => {
    router.get("/exercises").get((req, res) => {
        User.find()
            .then(users => res.json(exercises))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
    });

};
```